# Possible for instantiated sub class to access property set by parent class?

Tags: php

I'm new to object-oriented PHP, and still wrapping my head around classes and subclasses.

In this simple example, `$this->siteName` will be empty inside the instantiated class Two (called from class One's method "build").

Is there any way for an instance of class Two to inherit that property value set by the parent?

I know I could just turn class Two into a method of class One, but I like having separate files for organization.

Is there a better way to do this?

**File One**

```
class One {

  protected $siteName;

  function __construct() {
    $this->siteName = 'Example';
  }

  public function build() {
    $two = new Two();
    return $two->build();
  }

}
```

**File Two**

```
class Two extends One {

  public function build() {
    return "<h1>$this->siteName</h1>";
  }

}
```

Comment: That will work. That is how it is supposed to work. Did you actually try it yet? Its called testing

Comment: Yea. Since $two is its own instance, `$one->build()` wouldn't return "Example" because that property is set in the parent instance, but not the subclass instance.

Comment: It does for me so what are you doing differently

Comment: You're right, I was testing it with the real code and the issue is I have a __constructor in the subclass. When I remove that (like in this example), the instance does inherit the parent value.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

My understanding of your question is that you basically want to have the code for `public function build()` in another file for organisation reasons.

Here's how:

```
class One {
    private $siteName;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->siteName = 'Example';
    }

    use One_build;
}
```

Assuming you have the proper autoloading setup, or have included the files correctly, you can then have your separate file:

```
trait One_build {
    public function build() {
        return "<h1>".$this->siteName."</h1>";
    }
}
```

This allows for a horizontal spreading of your source code.

Comment: Ok, so that's definitely interesting. I didn't know about traits. A more realistic example is `class Header` and `class Head extends Header`. I'm wanting to use `class Head` as a stand-alone to create a head element or as part of `class Header`, which would create a head and a header. Not sure if that changes things or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work with a few tweaks. You need to concatenate your string's h1 tags with your variable, quotes can't be around the entire thing.

Other than that, just create an instance of the class and trying it out.

```
class One {

  protected $siteName;

  function __construct() {
    $this->siteName = 'Example';
  }

  public function build() {
    $two = new Two();
    return $two->build();
  }

}

class Two extends One {

  public function build() {
    return "<h1>".$this->siteName."</h1>";
  }

}

$taco = new Two();
echo $taco->build();
```

This will return `<h1>Example</h1>`